# How do I set Listener on

Tags: java, android-studio

I want to set  click Option on **BottomAppBar**,make this change page like **intent**.

What should I do next?

Sorry I'm from Taiwanese,so my english is not good...

hope you can understand my question.

Thank you

[This is my picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWPhi.png)

This is my code **Avtivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar;

public class homefunction_code extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button record,Act,MVnBook,Resourse,Start;
    BottomAppBar bar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.homefunction);

        bar = (BottomAppBar) findViewById(R.id.bottomAppBar);
//        bar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(itemClick);
```

Answer (score 0):

To "listen" a click on your bar, you need to use this method :

```
View.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()) { // set listener
  Intent newActivityIntent = new Intent(homefunction_code.this, nextactivity.class);
  startActivity(newActivityIntent) // change activity
  overridePendingTransition(0, 0); //avoid animation
}
```